# C# Automapper. Ошибка маппинга GUID и string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Есть 2 модели `DocumentBLL` и `DocumentStatusDb`

При маппинге `_mapper.Map<DocumentStatusDb>(document)` получаю Exception -

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
DocumentBLL -> DocumentStatusDb
LAMS.Logic.Common.Models.Documents.DocumentBLL -> LAMS.DataAccess.Common.Models.Documents.DocumentStatusDb

Type Map configuration:
DocumentBLL -> DocumentStatusDb
LAMS.Logic.Common.Models.Documents.DocumentBLL -> LAMS.DataAccess.Common.Models.Documents.DocumentStatusDb

Property:
Id

Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Классы

```
DocumentBLL
public string Id { get; set; }

DocumentStatusDb
public int Id { get; set; }
public string DocumentId { get; set; }
```

Маппер

```
public class DocumentStatusProfile : Profile
{
   public DocumentStatusProfile()
   {
      CreateMap<DocumentBLL, DocumentStatusDb>()
        .ForMember(m => m.DocumentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id));
   }
}
```

Куски из конфигураций EF:

```
public class DocumentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentStatusDb>
    HasKey(x => x.Id);            
    Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(a => a.DocumentId).HasMaxLength(128);

public class DocumentStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentDb>
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

Таким образом задаю Id, который потом надо смаппить
`documentBLL.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`

Когда `Id` были `int` все было норм.

Comment: в классе `DocumentStatusDb` поле `id` откуда мапится?

Comment: ниоткуда( добавил .ForMember(m => m.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()) и ок. Можете пояснить почему так? Я думал, что раз указал что куда мапить, то проблем не будет, а он пытался маппить Id и ,соответственно, ошибка при приведении string к int

Comment: Потому что по умолчанию маппер мапит свойства с одинаковыми именами. Вы правил маппинга для id не указали, вот он и мапил по умолчанию id на id

Comment: Используйте для преобразования типов BeforeMap и AfterMap: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html